# how to print sentence is pangram or not. i m getting Timeout in c

Tags: c

I have to find  sentences is pangram(Pangrams are sentences constructed by using every letter of the alphabet at least once) or not

Terminated due to timeout . why it seems ok to me  ? how thinks work . i m using this on  hackerrank . t

plz tell what is a  better ways to solve with logical reasoning. THis is too much but  plz help :)

This is best what i can do plz help me .. thanks in advance and if something big mistake in program sorry

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,n=0,l;
    char str[1000];

    scanf("%[^\n]%*c",str);

    for(l=65;i<91;l++)
    {
        for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';)
        {
            if(l==str[i]&&l+31==str[i])
            {
               n++;
            }

            if(str[i+1]=='\0')
            {  i=i+2;

            }
            else
            i++;
        }
    }


    if(n==26)
        printf("pangram ");
    else
        printf(" not pangram ");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please put a minimum of effort at looking at your own post before posting it here. Most importantly, fix the indention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code as follow :

```
int a[27];count=0;
for(k=0;k<27;k++)
    a[k]=0;
for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
{
    if(str[i]>96 && str[i]<123)
        a[str[i]-96]++;
    else if(str[i]>64 && str[i]<91)
        a[str[i]-64]++;
}
for(k=1;k<27;k++)
   if(a[k]>0)
      count++;
if(count==26)
    printf("panagram");
```

Comment: What if your string has punctuation or numbers?

Comment: Pangrams are words or sentences containing every letter of the alphabet at least once.Punctuation and Numbers are excluded.

Comment: I know what a pangram is, thanks. My comment was inteded to point out a flaw in your program, namely that every character that isn't a space or lower-case letter (or curly brace or pipe symbol or tilde) is treated as upper-case letter, which will very likely result in illegal indices for `a`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo on

```
for(l=65;i<91;l++)
```

Should be

```
for(l=65;l<91;l++)
```

Another problematic thing that can invoke [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) is the code

```
if(str[i+1]=='\0')
{
   i=i+2;
   printf(".-----------%d --- %c\n", i, str[i]);
}
```

Beacuse of is inside `for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';)`

It means that each time a `null` terminator is found the for continue until a sequence of `"\0\0"` is found. This will invoce [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because of your `str` is not inited and anyway if `str` will be `1000` chars long.

Comment: Then flag the question as off-topic.

Comment: One of the off-topic reasons is: _“This question was caused by a **problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error**. […]”_.

Comment: I desagree. This is a typo error, but OP is not seeing it. Then an answer is appreciated, I think.

Comment: Usually a comment is sufficient in that case.

Comment: @Xufox Added something else to fit requirements :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a simpler and faster approach like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[1000];
    scanf("%s", str);
    int c[26] = {0}, ans = 1;
    for (int i = 0; str[i]; ++i)
        if (isalpha(str[i]))    // Only if alphabet
            c[tolower(str[i]) - 'a']++;
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
        if (!c[i]) {    // Break if not pangram
            ans = 0;
            break;
        }
    printf(ans ? "pangram" : "not pangram");
    return 0;
}
```

> Time Complexity **O(string length + constant)**